# Getting past a validation

Tags: validation-rule

A client is using the same contact object for two project. One requires a field validation on a specific field. The other project does not need this field. There is a profile for each project. Do I just remove field access to the field for the profile of the project that doesn't need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing field access does not affect validation rules as such. If, for example, your validation rule requires that field `Required__c` be populated, users who can't see `Required__c` will still see errors when they save if the field is blank.

If your validation rule should be active only for a specific profile, you can include a check for `$Profile.Name` in your validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove it from the profile it will not show up in the layouts  but if there is a validation rule based on that field it will still fire.

Your best  bet is to have a field like 'Project' and say if its value = 'ABC' then trigger it and if not the validation rule will not fire. This will also ensure that it only fires for that one particular project.